# Python Dynamic Call; getattr?

Tags: python

normally I can hack bits of code together with some googling but this one is a little far outside my understanding. I am looking to programatically run the following function;

```
App.getDocument("Unnamed").NAME.Placement=App.Placement(App.Vector(0,0,0), App.Rotation(App.Vector(0,0,1),90), App.Vector(0,0,0))
```

where NAME and the numbers are the items that change. ie I have NAME1, NAME2 .... NAMEn each with difference vector numbers and I'd like run this command in a for loop to move however many items the script has been passed. From a quick search getattr() seemed to be the answer but the = seems to be the blocker. So I can only get as far as this;

```
f1 = getattr(App,'getDocument')
f2 = getattr(f1('Unnamed'),'NAME1')
f3 = getattr(f2,'Placement')
```

Comment: try `f2.Placement=App.Placement(App.Vector(0,0,0), App.Rotation(App.Vecto....`

Comment: with  `f2=getattr(App.getDocument("Unnamed"), 'NAME1')`

Comment: Haha, of course! Sometimes you can't see what's right in front of you, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
names = ['NAME1','NAME2','NAME3'] ...
vectors = [[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)], 
           [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)], 
           [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)],] 

for n, (v1,v2,v3) in zip(names, vectors):
    left = getattr(App.getDocument("Unnamed"),n)
    right = App.Placement(App.Vector(*v1), App.Rotation(App.Vector(*v2),90), App.Vector(*v3))

    setattr(left, "Placement", right)
```

Comment: no need for `setattr()` here, just `left.Placement=right`